# How can I create a reactive meteor publication with a variable momentjs date

Tags: meteor, momentjs

I'm having trouble with realizing a reactive publication with a moving date. I have a calendar app with events/meetings. Im displaying these events on a special view page but i only want to display events of today and only with a starting time of currenttime - 30 mins.

The code im having and trying always works fine on initial load, after refreshing and when I add/delete an event from an admin page (collection gets refreshed?). But when I leave the page open the events which have passed just stay on the page. Whenever I add/remove a event via the admin page the publication is updated just fine. I assume this is because the publication isn't refreshing the date in the query or something?

I have tried:

- normal publications and just subscribing via either iron-router
  before hook or via Deps.autorun
- publish all events and filtering on the client side
- a publication with observeChanges
- keep the vars in a deps.autorun function and passing them via the subscription as parameters

but I just keep getting the same results.

publication with observeChanges:

```
Meteor.publish('currentEventsObserve', function(calId) {

  var self = this;

   var nowMin30mins = moment().subtract('minutes',30).valueOf();
   var endOfToday = moment(moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY 23:59'),  'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm').valueOf(); 

  var handle = Events.find({
      calId : calId, //CalendarId
      eventDate: { $gt: nowMin30mins, $lt: endOfToday }
    },
    {
      sort: { eventDate: 1 },
      limit: 5
    }).observeChanges({

    added: function(id,event){
      //console.log("added: ",id,event);
      self.added("events", id, event);
    },

    removed: function (id,event) {
      //console.log("removed: ",id,event);
      self.removed("events", id);      
    }

  });

  self.ready();

  self.onStop(function () {
    handle.stop();
  });

});
```

As said before: the above works fine on initial load and refreshes, but after leaving the page open for a while the events are staying on there and not being removed from the publication.

Also, whenever I check the collection ones certain events already should have been removed via Events.find().fetch() for example, the events are still there, so it's not the template which isn't updating correctly.

I hope it's clear what I mean. I have read many other questions about this sort of reactivity but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `nowMin30mins` is only computed once when the publication is activated, and won't update afterwards, even though you have an `observeChanges` on `Events`. You basically have two constant values (`nowMin30mins` and `endOfToday`) bracketing the documents that will be shown and only adding or removing items will cause them to disappear.

I can think of two ways for how you'd want to do this reactively.

- You can put all the reactivity on the client. Just send the entire day's events over in a publish, which is very simple, and have the client filter out what's between 30 mins from now and the end of the day using `Date.now()` in a computation that updates every minute or so, or when new events are added/deleted. It doesn't seem to incur a lot of overhead to store those events anyway and you can offload the computational cost of observes, which can build up if you have a lot of clients
- If you want to do it on the server, you'll have to do things a little more carefully than what you have now. Because the live query won't account for the change in time, you'll need to watch all of today's events and then add or remove them from the subscription if they are created, or deleted or go out of range, respectively. To reiterate, you can't do this purely with an `observeChanges` because the current time is always changing.